# Do I need to use an F test as well as quasibinomial for over dispersed data

Tags: r, proportion

I'm carrying out a GLM on proportion data (derived from counts)

After carrying out a GLM with the quasibinomial error distribution (my data is non-integer)

`model=glm(response~predictor1+predictor2, data=df, family=quasibinomial(link=logit)`

After which I get a summary which shows that the data is not overdispersed

I was wondering if it is appropriate to use a chi-sq anova test with this or whether I should use an F test?

Answer (score 1):

If the `response` is a proportion obtained from counts, then the total count for each response must be specified to the binomial glm as a weight. As it is, you are inputing proportions to `glm` but withholding crucial information about the precision of those proportions. As it is, there is no valid way that you can conclude lack of overdispersion from the glm summary.

You should in general use a quasi F-test, unless you can fit a genuine binomial model and conclude that there is no overdispersion.